# Sum of two indicator functions: $\mathbb{1}_A - \mathbb{1}_B$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}^d$. Let us recall that $\mathbb{1}_A$ is the indicator function of $A$ defined by: $\mathbb{1}_A(x)=1$ if $x \in A$ and equals to zero otherwise.

Now, I m looking for $\mathbb{1}_A-\mathbb{1}_B$, so computed the folllowing:
$\mathbb{1}_A(x)-\mathbb{1}_B(x)=0$ is $x \in A \cap B$, equals to $1$ if $x \in A\backslash B$ (if $B \subset A$), equals to $-1$ if $x \in B\backslash A$ (if $A \subset B$).

Is there a better representation of $\mathbb{1}_A-\mathbb{1}_B$?

Comment: what do you mean by "better representation"?

Comment: Not really. Except it is interesting to note that, your quantity modulo $2$ indicates the [symmetric set difference](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference)

Comment: Do you want sum or difference?

Comment: @Paul the difference.

Comment: @psl2Z In the above repsentation I give the expression of the difference in three cases ; If $A \subset B$ and $B\subset A$ but can I represent it in one simple case?

Comment: Your description missed the points outside of $A \cup B$.